Angular Material Selection List Issues
I've been having some issues with the "mat-selection-list" provided by Angular Material lately.
I have integrated a simple "mat-selection-list" into my web app and displayed a few "mat-list-options" using *ngFor and a string array. However, every interaction with the list options leads to problems:
When I select a list option, the field of the list option suddenly enlarges for about 0.5 seconds, and the checkbox is displayed in the lower left corner of the list option. I was able to partially fix this by limiting the max-height of the list option, but the checkbox still briefly shifts right after being checked, and the text value of the list option is not displayed during that short time. (Sorry for the horrible quality but you should recognize what I mean: Screenhshot)
I set the multiple attribute to false on the mat-selection-list to ensure that no more than one option can be checked at a time. Unfortunately, this does not work as intended, because I can still select multiple options simultaneously, but I cannot uncheck them.
All in all, these are very strange problems that I have never experienced with Angular Material before.
.html
<div class="bodyDiv">
        <mat-selection-list [multiple]="false" *ngFor="let p of participants">
            <mat-list-option class="listItem">{{p}}</mat-list-option>
        </mat-selection-list>
    </div>

I have already reinstalled the node modules and searched the internet for similar issues but found nothing comparable. I attempted to remove all CSS modifications I had made that could potentially affect the list's behavior, but this did not resolve the issue.

Can you provide us your Angular CLI version and also for Angular Material, to be able to reproduce your iissue

Please provide a stackblitz link
